# how to change the logo in aws sso saml application

Tags: single-sign-on, aws-sso

I have enabled the aws sso in that created one saml Application, when we login using aws sso we can able to see the saml application,but i cant able to change the logo of application, is there any way to change the icon/logo of saml application?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfwxV.png)

any suggestion that would be helpful for me.